# The flag to mark a question for another StackExchange is incomplete

Tags: feature-request, flagging, migration

When you follow the wizard to flag a question as off topic, the only migration option is to mark it as part of the Graphic Design Meta, and there is no option to mark it as StackOverflow, Blender, or Video, for example.

Those options would be nice.